# Image don't display in outlook when I created a meeting invitation email

Tags: image, outlook, conference

I created a meeting invitation email and inserted an image in it(not through outlook).
But when I use Outlook 2013 to receive this mail, the picture is displayed as an icon.

Comment: You really need to show your code.

Comment: Could you share your code for us better understanding your question ? For more issue related “Images Not Displaying in an Email Client” , please review here: https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/5554-images-not-displaying-in-an-email-client?lang=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of outlook 2013, here is the answer : https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/help/3128018